# Generate a java class via xsd and also add a class attribute not present in the xsd file

Tags: java, serialization, xjc

I'm sorry for my bad english, I periodically receive this xsd file with slight updates, and from this file I generate a class via xjc, I would like that in addition to what is specified in the file, xjc also adds an integer type attribute, possibly with its transient getter and setter methods.

Do you know how to do that? Or maybe another plugin that can do that

I tried searching online and in the documentation and I found nothing

Comment: You should provide more details including a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example